# how to set up a checked list item list view on android

Tags: android, listview

I am using the listView widget on android, and in preview list content I chose "checked list" item
Basically it is a list of items and I should be able to check some items and when I do the check mark next to the item becomes visible (it isn't a checkbox, that is the difference between many other checkable lists)
I don't know how to use it, I would like to know at least how I can check some item, that is make the check mark visible, because when I click on an item, it is clickable but nothing happens...

[image of listview in simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udin7.png)

[image of listview in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygnb7.png)

here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:rsb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#fffefdff">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="540dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutPreferences"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:divider="#ff080808"
    android:dividerPadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_checked"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:contextClickable="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is my java file

```
public class Popneighbourhood extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listNeighbourhood;
String[] neighbourhood = new String[]{
        "Alamo Square/NOPA", "Castro/Upper Market", "Central Richmond", "Cole Valley/Ashbury Heights", "Downtown/Civic/Van Ness", "Duboce Triangle",
        "Financial District", "Glen Park", "Haight Ashbury", "Hayes Vallez", "Ingleside/SFSU/CCSF", "Inner Richmond",
        "Inner Sunset/UCSF", "Jordan Park/Laurel Heights", "Laurel Heights/Presidio", "Lower Haight", "Lower Nob Hill", "Lower Pac Heights",
        "Marina/Cow Hollow", "Mission Bay", "Mission District", "Nob Hill", "Noe Valley", "North Beach/Telegraph Hill",
        "Oakland North/Temescal", "Pacific Heights"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_popneighbourhood);
    ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.logofrontdoor);

    listNeighbourhood = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    //android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 est une vue disponible de base dans le SDK android,
    //Contenant une TextView avec comme identifiant "@android:id/text1"

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Popneighbourhood.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, neighbourhood);
   listNeighbourhood.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

//adapter code , i just took one of the adapter source from my project, notice the imageView, iv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list_select, is toggled when you select.

```
public class DashboardCountryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Country> mCountryList = new ArrayList<>();

    public DashboardCountryListAdapter(Context context, List<Country> countryList) {
        mContext = context;
        mCountryList = countryList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCountryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mCountryList.isEmpty() ? null : mCountryList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard_country_list, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (!mCountryList.isEmpty()) {
            Country country = mCountryList.get(position);
            int image = country.getImage();
            if (image != -1) {
                viewHolder.iv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list.setImageResource(image);
                if (country.getSelected()){
                    viewHolder.iv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list_select.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                    viewHolder.iv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list_select.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            viewHolder.tv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list.setText(country.getName());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.iv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list)
        ImageView iv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list)
        TextView tv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list;
        @Bind(R.id.iv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list_select)
        ImageView iv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list_select;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }

    public void updateList(List<Country> list) {
        mCountryList = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

//xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp" />

    <com.UTU.View.UtuTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list"
        android:textColor="@color/chic_black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_item_fragment_dashboard_country_list_select"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_check_teal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="13dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you why the editor looks different from the running app:

In your layout XML the list view has this attribute:

```
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_checked"
```

but in your code you have

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Popneighbourhood.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, neighbourhood);
```

so you're using an entirely different layout for the list item.

You need to put `R.layout.simple_list_item_checked` in the adapter constructor, and you will probably need to change to the constructor that specifies the id of the `TextView` to use.

Comment: thank you, I have changed the attribute, on the simulator, I can now select the different items, how can I work with these items, I would like to know how to get the count of the selected items... the function getCheckedItemCount does not return anything, it seems as though the checkmarks are just there for the image but they aren't recognised... I'm quite new to this and I'm having a hard time with this list view